# How to mock method if it is getting called multiple times with different attributes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, fabric

I am writing unit tests for my Python and Fabric based code. I have following method which in turn calls `sudo` method of Fabric API multiple times with different arguments. I would like to know how to call assert on mock `sudo` object.

```
**main_file.py**

from fabric.api import sudo

def do_something(path_to_file_to_be_copied, destination_path):
    # remove file if already exists
    sudo('rm ' + path_to_file_to_be_copied, warn_only=True)
    sudo('cp ' + path_to_file_to_be_copied + ' ' + destination_path)
```

I have written test file as below :

```
**test_main_file.py**

import main_file

class MainFileTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('main_file.sudo')
    def test_do_something(self, mock_sudo):
        file_path = '/dummy/file/path.txt'
        dest_dir = '/path/to/dest/dir'
        main_file.do_something(file_path, dest_dir)
        mock_sudo.assert_called_with('rm ' + file_path)
```

Above test fails because mocked object remembers only last call. that is, if I write `mock_sudo.assert_called_with(cp + file_path + ' ' + dest_dir)`  then test fails.

How can I assert both the calls to `sudo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`assert_any_call`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.assert_any_call) which asserts whether there has been *any* call, not just the most recent one.

Or, you can use [`call_args_list`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.call_args_list) to get the list of args the mock has been called with.

Answer (score 3):

[assert_has_calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) will do the job for you.

> **assert_has_calls :** assert the mock has been called with the specified calls. The mock_calls list is checked for the calls.
>   If any_order is true then the calls can be in any order, but they must all appear in mock_calls.

```
import main_file
class MainFileTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('main_file.sudo')
    def test_do_something(self, mock_sudo):
        file_path = '/dummy/file/path.txt'
        dest_dir = '/path/to/dest/dir'
        main_file.do_something(file_path, dest_dir)
        mock_sudo.assert_has_calls(['rm ' + file_path,
                                    'cp' + file_path + ' ' + dest_dir],
                                     any_order=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [helper library](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) to automatically generate the asserts for me.

Add those lines to print the correct asserts for your case, right after `main_file.do_something(file_path, dest_dir)`:

```
import mock_autogen.generator
print(mock_autogen.generator.generate_asserts(mock_sudo))
```

You would get the following output:

```
from mock import call

assert 2 == mock_sudo.call_count
mock_sudo.assert_has_calls(
    calls=[call('rm /dummy/file/path.txt', warn_only=True),
           call('cp /dummy/file/path.txt /path/to/dest/dir'), ])
```

No need to guess anymore, use [mock-generator](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) :)